# Is there a way to use a Texture2D as a base for an enum

Tags: c#, enums, xna

I want to use a Texture2D for a base enum.  Similar to the way Color Works.  ie. Color.Black

This doesn't compile, because you can't use Texture2D as a base, I am using this code to demonstrate what I want.

```
public class Content
{
    public Dictionary<string,Texture2D> Textures =new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();
}


public enum Texture:Texture2D
{
    Player = Content.Textures["Player"],
    BackGround = Content.Textures["BackGround"],
    SelectedBox = Content.Textures["SelectedBox"],
    Border = Content.Textures["Border"],
    HostButton = Content.Textures["HostButton"]
}
```

Which could then be used like

```
Texture2D myTexture= Content.Texture.Player;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use objects as a base for enums. What you can do is add your different textures as static properties to a class:

```
public static class Texture
{
    public static Texture2D Player { get; private set; }
    public static Texture2D BackGround { get; private set; }
    ...

    static Texture()
    {
        Player = Content.Textures["Player"];
        BackGround = Content.Textures["BackGround"];
        ...
    }
}
```

That way you can use them like you want:

```
Texture2D myTexture = Texture.Player;
```

Comment: I like this one, it basically does the same thing as enum.